# How to use awk to extract a YAML metadata block

Tags: awk, yaml

I have many Markdown files with a YAML metadata block at the top:

```
---
title: title of work
author: author name
author-sort: name, author
published: N
date: XXXX-XX-XX
pub-number: XXXXX
embedded-title: false
---

**title**

a piece of indertimate  
length that could be a few lines of many hundreds

---[author name](author link)
---found in [source](source link)
```

I am trying to find a way to extract the metadata block (so I can feed it into `yamllint`, but later other things as well). Awk seems like the right tool, but hacking together in awk when I don't understand it, the best I have come up with is this:

```
awk '/^---$/ {printline = 1; print; next} /^---$/ {printline = 0} printline'
```

This just shows the whole file, my attempt to limit to the `---` lines on their own isn't working (and maybe nothing else here is)!

Answer (score 6):

`sed` may be a better choice of tool.  Since this is always at the top of the file you can tell `sed` to only print from line 2 until the `---` line, and then delete that line.

eg

```
sed -n '2,/^---$/ {/^---$/d; p}'
```

This works by:

```
-n: don't print by default
2,/^---$/ { ... }: limit the next part to the lines between line 2 and the first line matching ---
```

And then inside that block

```
/^----$/d : delete the --- line
p : print what remains.
```

So on your test file the output is

```
title: title of work
author: author name
author-sort: name, author
published: N
date: XXXX-XX-XX
pub-number: XXXXX
embedded-title: false
```

To do it in `awk` would require tracking state.  e.g

```
awk '
/^---$/ && printline==0 {printline = 1;next}
/^---$/ {printline = 2; next}
{ if (printline==1) { print } }
'
```

This state would be required just in case you had a `---` line in the rest of the file.

Answer (score 5):

As the metadata block is delimited by `---` as a separator, we can set the record separator/`RS` to this.

With the assumption that the metadata block is always at the beginning of the yaml file and separated by `---`, it is safe to also assume that the second record will be the metadata block, so we can say:

```
➜ awk 'BEGIN { RS = "---" } NR==2' example-yaml.txt 

title: title of work
author: author name
author-sort: name, author
published: N
date: XXXX-XX-XX
pub-number: XXXXX
embedded-title: false
```

to extract it.

`awk` defaults to newlines as a record separator but (at least in GNU awk, other awk implementations may differ as I haven't verified this for other than gawk) it can be set to any/multiple characters as well as regex (see [awk split records (The GNU Awk User’s Guide)](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/awk-split-records.html) for reference).

Comment: POSIX says the results are “unspecified” if RS contains more than one character.

Answer (score 4):

With a [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) one-liner:

```
$ perl -0ne 'print $1 if /^---\n(.*)^---$/ms' file.yaml  
title: title of work
author: author name
author-sort: name, author
published: N
date: XXXX-XX-XX
pub-number: XXXXX
embedded-title: false
```

Answer (score 4):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{printline=2} /^---$/{printline--; next} printline' file.yaml
title: title of work
author: author name
author-sort: name, author
published: N
date: XXXX-XX-XX
pub-number: XXXXX
embedded-title: false
```

`printline` at the end of the command is a kind of *print* statement, as far as `awk` default behavior on a positive integer is to print the whole line. At the beginning, the `printline` variable is set to 2 and then decremented each times the regex `^---$` match. So when `printline` is zero, `awk` stop printing.

Answer (score 4):

Using the [ed](/questions/tagged/ed) editor to delete everything from the second YAML document separator `---` to the end of the document, and then display what remains:

```bash
$ printf '%s\n' '1;/^---$/,$d' ,p Q | ed -s file
---
title: title of work
author: author name
author-sort: name, author
published: N
date: XXXX-XX-XX
pub-number: XXXXX
embedded-title: false
```

---

Reversing all the lines, deleting up to the first `---` delimiter (which will be the one at the end of the YAML section, and then reversing the lines again:

```bash
$ tail -r file | sed '1,/^---$/d' | tail -r
---
title: title of work
author: author name
author-sort: name, author
published: N
date: XXXX-XX-XX
pub-number: XXXXX
embedded-title: false
```

If your implementation of [tail](/questions/tagged/tail) does not have the `-r` option (available on macOS and other BSD systems), you may use GNU [tac](/questions/tagged/tac) instead.